# Setting session/request attributes using amplify Interactions.send

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-lex

I am using Amplify.Interactions (Lex) in a Vue.js project. I can successfully send and receive text messages. I am having difficulties specifying requestAttributes or sessionAttributes value on my request. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

The following code works

```
Interactions.send("botname", {
    content: "some text,
    options: {
      messageType: "text"
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      logger.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      logger.error(error);
    });
```

But when I try to send the following object (in content) the bot doesn't identify the correct intent.

```
JSON.stringify({
 inputText: "some text",
 sessionAttributes: { attr1: "val1", attr2: "val2" }
 })
```